# Match the column value in a df with the column value of another df with the specific format?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

df1

```
Model              Version

ANALYST7000         8.2.1.0
ANALYSTMM           4.5.6.4
PA-500              4.56.67
PA-4000             8.7.89
PA-5000             9.0.5.6
PA-7000             4.5.6.7
```

df2

```
Model

ANALYST7245
ANALYST7200XM
ANALYSTMM
PA-570
PA-5460
PA-5790
PA-7000
```

OUTPUT

```
ANALYST7245      8.2.1.0
ANALYST7200XM      8.2.1.0
ANALYSTMM          4.5.6.4
PA-570            4.56.67
PA-5460           9.0.5.6
PA-5790           9.0.5.6
PA-7000           4.5.6.7
```

I have two data frame df1 and df2
I want the output presented above, the model in df match the model in df2 like ANALYST those who falls under seven thousand and PA those who fall under five hundred, four thousand and soon category

Answer (score 1):

If need replace all digits after first digit to `0` and then map column `Model` by first `DataFrame` use:

```
df2['Version'] = [f'{a}{b}{"0" * len(c)}' for a,b, c in df2['Model'].str.split('(\d)', n=1)]
print (df2)
          Model       Version
0  ANALYST72450  ANALYST70000 <- added 4 times 0 by length
1  ANALYST720XM  ANALYST70000
2        PA-570        PA-500
3       PA-5460       PA-5000
4       PA-5790       PA-5000
5       PA-7000       PA-7000

df2['Version'] = df2['Version'].map(df1.set_index('Model')['Version'])
print (df2)


          Model  Version
0  ANALYST72450      NaN <- not matched ANALYST7000 to ANALYST70000, so NaN
1  ANALYST720XM      NaN
2        PA-570  4.56.67
3       PA-5460  9.0.5.6
4       PA-5790  9.0.5.6
5       PA-7000  4.5.6.7
```

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question for ANALYST720XM I made ANALYST7200XM, I just want to match the  ANALYST7200 only not XM.

Comment: @jezreal CAN U HELP ME WITH THE ABOVE EDITED ONE.